# nginx cant connect to phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble connecting to `phpmyadmin` using my current `nginx` configuration.

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/couponmonk_project**

```
server {

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/giri/couponmonk_project/couponmonk_project/static;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;        
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;        
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/socket.io;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

}
```

When I try and access `phpmyadmin` using `my_ip_address/phpmyadmin`, I get a `404 Not Found` error. My other paths seem to be working fine.

The folder `/usr/share/nginx/www/phpmyadmin` contains the `index.php` file. As a quick test, I inserted an `index.html` file here and it was correctly displayed.

Has it something to do with `fastcgi_params`? I'm not sure how/if this file should be edited.

Any ideas as to what I should try would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised I just needed to move:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
...
}
```

inside:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
....
}
```

**.conf**

```
server {

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
      proxy_redirect off;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
  location /static {
      alias  /home/giri/couponmonk_project/couponmonk_project/static;
  }

  location /phpmyadmin {
      root /usr/share/nginx/www;        
      index  index.html index.htm index.php;        

     # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
     location ~ \.php$ {
     try_files $uri =404;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     }
  }


  location /socket.io {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/socket.io;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;

      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }

}
```